# How to set default_schema in jhipster app with postgresql database?

Tags: jhipster

I'm using jhipster to develop an application and now I want to use an existing postgres database. So I choosed to add a new schema to the database and now I want to set in my application_dev.yml file the default schema. For that I tried this:

```
      properties:
             hibernate.default_schema: My_SCHEMA
```

still not working but when I do

```
liquibase:
        default-schema: My_SCHEMA
```

it's working.
How to have the same result using

#### spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=My_SCHEMA

## Thanks in advance !

Comment: what error do you get when using `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=My_SCHEMA`?

Comment: Not an error, it's just using the default schema public, but when I config with liquibase it's working